# Use Stripe create connect account not get correct url

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using PHP to create a connected account information, I refer to this URL https://docs.stripe.com/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide, when I create a connected Account in the official environment, I cannot get something like this screen, how should I solve it

[image]

this is my php code

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_live_xxxxx');


$createaccount = $stripe->accounts->create([
    'type' => 'express',
    'country' => 'US',
    'email' => 'simpson@google.com',
    'capabilities' => [
      'card_payments' => ['requested' => true],
      'transfers' => ['requested' => true],
    ],
]);
  
$createlinks = $stripe->accountLinks->create([
    'account' => $createaccount->id,
    'refresh_url' => 'https://example.com/reauth',
    'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
    'type' => 'account_onboarding',
]);
```

I will get `$createlinks->url` but this url directly to the stripe backend, unable to allow users to enter information

Comment: what does `$createlinks->url but this url directly to the stripe backend` mean? What's the value of `url`? What are you seeing when you open this link?

Comment: @alex When I was in the test environment, I opened this URL and got a screen for the user to fill in their personal information, like the screenshot I provided.

Comment: yes, but what did you get in production?

Comment: @alex In production, I get the URL, but when I opened this URL, it was linked to my stripe backend